# (Swift 3) How can we go to cell before ViewDidAppear() ? I want to show the cell just after user goes to this controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 12, section: 0)
    let theCell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

    if let theCell = theCell {
        var tableViewCenter:CGPoint = tableView.contentOffset
        tableViewCenter.y += tableView.frame.size.height/2

        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:theCell.center.y-(theCell.frame.size.height))
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jo.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = jo[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }   
}
```

When I go to this View I Want The Message to be Automatically Scrolled to the indexpath that i will give and the user should not be able to see the animation of scrolling it should appear before view did appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method on your table view:

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow)

```
func scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, 
              at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, 
        animated: Bool)
```

Usage:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)
```

In your case:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.reloadData()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 12, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Where to call this function as i want that user should not be able to see the scrolling when the view appears it should be at that index ?

Comment: viewWillAppear(), but try viewDidAppear() as well to see the difference

Comment: We cant Use in viewWillAppear As  The Below function is note executed that means cell is not made .  `override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jo.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = jo[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }`

Comment: Yes But In That Case User can See The Scrolling and i dont want user to see scrolling

Comment: Call the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it may work. override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() // call here
    }

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()  Didnt Work When Putting Code inside it Demo app freezes

Comment: try to put this code in viewWillAppear() { super.viewWillAppear(animated) tableView.reloadData()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 12, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false) }

Comment: If you want to hide scrolling then disable the animation of tableview scrolling in viewDidLoad and enable it back in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thanx The Above Code Worked

Comment: func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){super.viewWillAppear(false)
            self.tbl.reloadData()
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 999, section: 0)
            self.tbl.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)} .        when using this it will take to index 969 and if i use dispatchqueue.main.async{This code} then it will take to 999 but it will show some scrolling so how to solve this  @AlexanderGoncharov

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov

Comment: Try dispatchqueue.main.sync {} . But why do you have so many cells?

Comment: Its For Chat Section Thats Why . dispatchqueue.main.sync {} using this is causing app to crash and giving EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: Hm. If you want to scroll to the bottom, there is a different method.

Comment: Down Want To scroll to bottom just want to scroll to desired index. If scrolling to 560 cell then it shows 700 index one . Some mismatch There and when using dispatchqueue.main.async {} working fine but animation is shown first the table load from index one than it goes to other index(That we have given)  . I dont want user to see animation

Comment: I understood your problem. But usually server gives as response several dozens of chat messages, not hundreds. That's why maybe there is no simple solution for so many rows. I don't even know what to recommend you.

Comment: self.tbl.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 setting this value to 100 solved the problem

Comment: @Amey, Great! :)

Comment: setting this value to 100 solved the problem Your above code worked after changing this value from 20 to 100 Thanx Man @AlexanderGoncharov

Comment: Yeah, it helps the system to calculate the position where to scroll! It makes sense)